# HTML script constantly running?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to have javascript coffee always be checking the document? What I mean by this is if I have "if" statements, it will always check the document to see if it needs to run the script...

Also, it needs to not be a function that needs to be called. Here is some simple example of what I'm asking.

```
<button id="btn1">random button</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="hide()">hide</button>
<script>
    function hide() {
        document.getElementById("btn1").setAttribute("hidden", "true")
    }
</script>
<script>
    if (document.getElementById("btn1").hidden === true) {
        document.write("random button is hidden")
    }
</script>
```

How would I do something *like* this? I don't want this specifically, this is just an example.

In the code,a button hides another one, and there is script always checking if it is hidden. Please let me know.

**edit**

I see other people's answers, but it's not what I need. Is it possible to have functions constantly run without being called?

Comment: Look into setTimeout/setInterval or hook up an event to whatever hides the content!

Comment: @epascarello No, not in this case.

Comment: Like I said,I don't want this specific code. I have something more complicated that I need it to be checking multiple things and then run the code, and this can't be code that it's attached to a single event.

Comment: Explain in more detail.

Comment: So you need to add code that watches the state of the element with either setInterval or setTimeout or [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: It watches the state of multiple elements

Comment: No, it's impossible for a function to "always" run without freezing your tab. What you're asking sounds like a classic case of [XY](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/166899).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although I strongly recommend finding another way to do what you want, if possible, I think this is what you're asking for.

```
setInterval(function() {
    if(document.getElementById("btn1").hidden === true) {
        // Button is hidden
    }
}, 1000); // Wait 1000ms before running again
```

Comment: But how would I set this to always be checking?

Comment: Interval runs continuously, as in never-ending until the page is reloaded or the interval is cleared. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Decrease `1000` to `1`, then it will always checking it as long as you stay in the webpage.

Comment: @BryanWay Just in case he really want it to always check it

Comment: Thats true, but it's strongly recommended against. I agree with Second Rikudo that it should be event based, if not at least implemented in a set callback.

Comment: I think I can have it set to 1000, but where would i put this? In a script tag? And does it have to be alone?

Comment: @BryanWay It wouldn't actually run every 1ms... It run whenever it could, around 10ms most likely. It's not a terrible decision like you make it out to be

Comment: Guys please stop downvoting. Sure, it is a horrible solution, but @BryanWay made that very clear.

Comment: @jgillich If its horrible, it doesn't need to be mentioned in the first place. And my downvote is for the statement "_// Runs every 1 second (1000 milliseconds)_" from which someone new could understand that it is guaranteed to run on each second, which is false. That timeout represents the minimum time after which the code will be executed ; not a fixed and guaranteed time. Why minimum ? Because the event loop will push an item from the task queue in the stack only when the stack is empty, which can't be guaranteed to happen each second.

Comment: @AlexandruGuzinschi The answer is exactly what the OP asked for. I don't think it is fair to downvote somebody for answering a question correctly. Just don't upvote it, upvote "better" answers instead. About the interval, a comment would've done a much better job at pointing that out.

Comment: Where's all this activity coming from? @jgillich, I second that.

Comment: @AlexandruGuzinschi, Now you're just splitting hairs. Yes, setTimeout and setInterval are queued and may not run exactly every 1000 milliseconds, but what would you prefer? Measuring JS timing in CPU ticks for high resolution profiling?

Comment: **jgillich** I think you missed the point from my comment. **Bryan Way** I would have preferred to explain to the OP why this solution is not recommended and to provide an alternative solution to his problem. Also editing your answer and changing the statement "_// Runs every 1 second (1000 milliseconds)_" accordingly could be a good start.

Comment: I can change that comment, but if you take a look around you'll see that its been explained multiple times in multiple places.

Comment: @BryanWay True, but any bad habit can be changed. You edited your answer and changed that statement, so I removed my downvote. Although it looks like some people did not get the point, that statement (_i.e: Runs every 1 second (1000 milliseconds)_) was the only reason for my downvote in the first place. But anyway, let's call it a language barrier and move on. Only the best.

Answer (score 29):

JavaScript features what's called events. Any DOM element may emit events in response to user interaction. For example:

```
var button2 = document.querySelector('#btn2');
//            what event                 function to be called
//                       vvvvvvv  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
button2.addEventListener('click', function runThisOnButtonClick(event) {
    // Code in here will only run when the button is clicked.
    hideInSomeFashion(button1);
});
```

If you want a more general view of the DOM, recent browsers have what's called a **[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)**.

In your case, something like this [[example](http://jsfiddle.net/meyt79L5/)]:

```
// Older versions of Webkit have this under a prefix
var MutationObserver = MutationObserver || WebkitMutationObserver; 
var myMo = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    // handleMutation in this case is a function that takes
    // a mutation and performs an action. Note that in this
    // case, return values are ignored.
    mutations.forEach(handleMutation);
});
myMo.observe(button1, {
    attributes: true // Observe changes in attributes
});

function handleMutation(mutation) {
    console.log("Hidden?", mutation.target.hidden);
}
```

`MutationObserver` can observe a common ancestor and all of its descendants for changes as well.

Comment: I can't use this, because the code to run shouldn't be attached to a single element or event

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. It's the most correct way of watching the DOM tree

Comment: @firebend77 then you attach it to the closest static container, and if need be the body element.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the if statement in an infinite loop:

```js
while (true) {
 // Code to repeatedly run
}
```

#### Edit:

Haven’t tested, but it might freeze your tab.